# Migrating from FuelPHP to Laravel: problem with one response

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, fuelphp

i'm migrating an old project from fuel to laravel and i'm having trouble with the response to one of the requests. The issue is, i need the response from laravel to be exactly the same as it was in fuel, because i already have the app in iOS and Android and having the same responses means i only need to change the endpoints. I can't seem to replicate the response here:

- FuelPHP code and response:

  ```
      $belongs = Model_Belong::find('all',array(
          'where'=>array(
              array('id_user',$id_user),
          ),
      ));

  return $this->createResponse(200, 'List', $belongs);
  *****RESPONSE****
  {
  "code": 200,
  "message": "List",
  "data": {
      "[1][1]": {
          "id_user": 1,
          "id_group": 1
      },
      "[1][2]": {
          "id_user": 1,
          "id_group": 2
      },
      "[1][3]": {
          "id_user": 1,
          "id_group": 3
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- Laravel code and response:

  ```
      $belongs = Belong::where('id_user', $id_user)
                  ->get();

  return $this->createResponse(200, 'List', $belongs);
  *****RESPONSE*****
  {
  "code": 200,
  "message": "List",
  "data": [
      {
          "id_user": 1,
          "id_group": 1,
      },
      {
          "id_user": 1,
          "id_group": 2,
      },
      {
          "id_user": 1,
          "id_group": 3,
      }
  ]
  }
  ```

***edit: createResponse() method

```
    function createResponse($code, $message, $data = [])
{
    if ($data == null) {
       $data = (object)[];
    }
    return response()->json([
        'code' => $code,
        'message' => $message,
        'data' => $data
    ]);

}
```

Comment: What does this createResponse() doe, as that is not a standard Fuel method? And Model_Belong, is that a standard Model, or an ORM model?

Comment: createResponse is a method i created to handle the responses (is the same for fuel and laravel) here is the code: (edited in the question)

And Model_Belong is ORM.

Comment: @MiguelHeredia if the `createResponse` method is the same, what does the `$belongs` data look like in fuel?

Comment: If i just var_dump belongs without my method, it gives this:
fuel: https://pastebin.com/Bvs1zqrz
laravel: https://pastebin.com/cfpmWVRG

Comment: It is the result of an ORM get(), so it's an array of Model_Belong objects. Hence my question what that method was doing with it, because hydrating an ORM object doesn't give that result.

Comment: The [1][1] is a coded index key, ORM model objects shouldn't be simply cast to an array.
The model probably has a compound PK, containing both id's, "[1][1]" is the internal ORM PK string representation.
I've never used Laravel, but I assume that just returns an indexed array instead of an assoc array, hence the output difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think a hacky solution can be done by producing own key by sql and retrieve it by using KeyBy() as following:

```
Belong::select([
        'id_user',
        'id_group', 
        DB::raw("CONCAT('[', id_user, '][', id_group, ']') as mykey")
    ])
    ->where('id_user', $id_user)
    ->get()
    ->keyBy('mykey');
```

Comment: or produce the key with a loop:

Comment: $result = Belong::where('id_user', $id_user)
                ->get();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $belongs["[$row->id_user][$row->id_group]"] = $row;
}

Comment: I get stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given with your code!

Comment: Seems it is related how you use the result in your application. Adding ->toArray() after keyBy() may help.